How to fix popup.js settings gui
const handleSettings = (func, value) => {
    if (func === "sfx") {
        sfxstate = value;
    }
    if (func === "music") {
        if (value) {
            bgmusic.volume = 1;
            musicstate = true;
        } else {
            bgmusic.volume = 0;
            musicstate = false;
        }
    }
};
const handlePopup = (popup) => {
    const shop = new Popup({ id: "sbclicker-SHOP", title: "Shop", content: `testshop` });
    const settings = new Popup({
        id: "sbclicker-SETTINGS",
        title: "Settings",
        content: `
        <button id="sbclicker-SETTINGS-SFX">${sfxstate ? "SFX: ON" : "SFX: OFF"}</button>
        <button id="sbclicker-SETTINGS-MUSIC">${musicstate ? "MUSIC: ON" : "MUSIC: OFF"}</button>
        <br>
        <p>Version: 1.0.0-dev</p>
        `,
        hideCallback: () => {
            $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-SFX").off("click");
            $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-MUSIC").off("click");
            console.log("[DEBUG] Settings buttons turned off successfully");
        },
    });
    const achievements = new Popup({ id: "sbclicker-ACHIEVEMENTS", title: "Achievements", content: `testachievements` });
    if (popup === "shop") {
        shop.show();
    } else if (popup === "settings") {
        settings.show();
        $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-SFX").on("click", () => {
            console.log("[DEBUG] SFX clicked");
            const newState = $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-SFX").text() === "SFX: ON" ? "off" : "on";
            $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-SFX").text(newState === "on" ? "SFX: ON" : "SFX: OFF");
            handleSettings("sfx", newState === "on");
        });
        $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-MUSIC").on("click", () => {
            console.log("[DEBUG] MUSIC clicked");
            const newState = $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-MUSIC").text() === "MUSIC: ON" ? "off" : "on";
            $("#sbclicker-SETTINGS-MUSIC").text(newState === "on" ? "MUSIC: ON" : "MUSIC: OFF");
            handleSettings("music", newState === "on");
        });
        console.log("[DEBUG] Settings buttons turned on successfully");
    } else if (popup === "achievements") {
        achievements.show();
    }
};
const turnOnHandlers = () => {
    $("#sbclicker-GAME-HEADER-SHOP").on("click", () => {
        console.log("[DEBUG] Shop clicked");
        handlePopup("shop");
    });
    $("#sbclicker-GAME-HEADER-ACHIEVEMENTS").on("click", () => {
        console.log("[DEBUG] Achievements clicked");
        handlePopup("achievements");
    });
    $("#sbclicker-GAME-HEADER-SETTINGS").on("click", () => {
        console.log("[DEBUG] Settings clicked");
        handlePopup("settings");
    });
    console.log("[DEBUG] Buttons turned on successfully");
};
setTimeout(turnOnHandlers, 100);


im writing a spacebar clicker game and when i first time open in-game settings (with music and sfx settings) everything works well but when i open next time it doesnt work
(i have everything imported correctly)
I tried changing to addEventListener, removeEventListener and it wasnt working
